# Ribbon icon doesn't show up in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

When I test an add-in in the Word 2016 for Windows, the ribbon image displays fine. When I side-load it in Word Online however, now image is displayed.

Do I need to add something else to the manifest to be compatible with the Word Online? The desktop version seems to automatically resize it for the ribbon, but does the Online version need a specific size?

[image: Online]
[image: Desktop]

Here is my relevant manifest:

```xml
<VersionOverrides 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="Document">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <GetStarted>
                    <Title resid="ISBW.GetStarted.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="ISBW.GetStarted.Description"/>
                    <LearnMoreUrl resid="ISBW.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
                </GetStarted>
                <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
                        <Group id="ISBW.Group1Id1">
                            <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                                <bt:Image size="20" resid="icon1_20x20" />
                                <bt:Image size="24" resid="icon1_24x24" />
                                <bt:Image size="40" resid="icon1_40x40" />
                                <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon1_64x64" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                                <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                                    <bt:Image size="20" resid="icon1_20x20" />
                                    <bt:Image size="24" resid="icon1_24x24" />
                                    <bt:Image size="40" resid="icon1_40x40" />
                                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon1_64x64" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon1_16x16" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon1_32x32" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon1_80x80" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon2_32x32" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon3_32x32" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon1_20x20" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon1_24x24" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon1_40x40" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon1_64x64" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/icon.png" />
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="residDesktopFuncUrl" DefaultValue="https://ishouldbewriting.net" />
            <bt:Url id="residUnitConverterUrl" DefaultValue="https://s3.amazonaws.com/isbw-word-addin/home.html" />
            <bt:Url id="ISBW.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://ishouldbewriting.net/about" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="residLabel" DefaultValue="ishouldbewriting.net" />
            <bt:String id="residLabel2" DefaultValue="ishouldbewriting.net" />
            <bt:String id="residLabel3" DefaultValue="Set Writing Goal" />
            <bt:String id="residLabel4" DefaultValue="ishouldbewriting.net" />
            <bt:String id="residLabel5" DefaultValue="Another Command" />
            <bt:String id="ISBW.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Set your writing goal" />
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="residToolTip" DefaultValue="ishouldbewriting.net" />
            <bt:String id="ISBW.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Set your writing goal by clicking this button" />
        </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some additional information such as the manifest and icon files would help.

Comment: Have you checked through some sort of proxy that you're in fact retrieving the image from your server?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when running in the browser (F12 tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're images should be rendered for the proper size. Currently you're declaring multiple image sizes but providing the same URI to a 654x720px image across them.

From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/design-icons#icon-size-recommendations-and-requirements):

> Office 2016 desktop icons are bitmap images. Different sizes will render depending on the user's DPI setting and touch mode. Include all eight supported sizes to create the best experience in all supported resolutions and contexts. The following are the supported sizes - three are required:
>
> - 16 px (Required)
> - 20 px
> - 24 px
> - 32 px (Required)
> - 40 px
> - 48 px
> - 64 px (Recommended, best for Mac)
> - 80 px (Required)

Comment: So the answer is... don't be lazy :) Thanks, now it works.